# Find the combination of a number set so that the total difference between two number sets is minimal

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Find the combinations of lots assigned from newLots into oldLots, so that the sum of differences between newLotCombinations and oldLots is optimal.
If a difference is less than 0, it counts as 0.
All lots from newLot must be assigned into newLotCombinations.

```
/**
 *
 * e.g.
 *
 *    newLots = [20.16, 9.95, 12.62, 7.44, 11.18, 9.02, 8.21, 8.22, 6.57, 6.63]
 *    oldLots = [12.03, 14.03, 16.04, 17.8, 18.04, 22.05]
 *
 *      newLotCombinations         |    oldLot     |     Difference (newLotCombinations - oldLot)
 *          20.16, 9.95            |    12.03      |          18.03 (20.16 + 9.95 - 12.03)
 *          12.62, 7.44            |    14.03      |          6.03 (12.62 + 7.44 - 14.03)
 *          11.18                  |    16.04      |            0
 *  ...
 *  ...
 * Sum of differences = 18.03 + 6.03 + 0 + ...
 */
```

I think this should involve memoizing the paths that I have gone through, like a map, and walking backward when a path is not correct (total sum larger than the assumption)

This is what I have so far:

```
const newLots = [20.16, 9.95, 12.62, 7.44, 11.18, 9.02, 8.21, 8.22, 6.57, 6.63]; // stack
const oldLots = [12.03, 14.03, 16.04, 17.8, 18.04, 22.05];
// newLotCombinations is an array of array [[], [], [], [], [], []] // i and j
const newLotCombinations = oldLots.map(() => []);

// Assuming the max. sum of differences is 5.
const MAX_SUM_OF_DIFFERENCES = 7;
const sum = 0;

// store information about a path?
const paths = {};

const loopLots = (i = 0, j = 0) => {
  if (i === -1) {
      console.log('it should not come to here');
    console.log(
      "No possible combination for max sum of differences:",
      MAX_SUM_OF_DIFFERENCES
    );
  } else if (!newLots.length) {
    console.log(
      "Combination that works with max sum of difference ",
      MAX_SUM_OF_DIFFERENCES,
      newLotCombinations
    );
  }
  newLotCombinations[i][j] = newLots.pop();

  if (getSumOfDifferences() > MAX_SUM_OF_DIFFERENCES) {
    // put it back to stack
    newLots.push(newLotCombinations[i].pop());
    if (i + 1 < newLotCombinations.length) {
      loopLots(i + 1, newLotCombinations[i+ 1].length);
    } else {
      // It keeps popping until an array has more than 1 element.      
      // But this is incorrect, as it will loop with 3 combinations of numbers
      // It should walk backward until last divergence
      while (newLotCombinations[i] && (i === newLotCombinations.length - 1 || newLotCombinations[i].length < 2)) {
        newLots.push(newLotCombinations[i].pop());
        i--;
      }
      if (newLotCombinations[i]) {
        newLots.push(newLotCombinations[i].pop());
        newLotCombinations[i + 1][newLotCombinations[i + 1].length] = newLots.pop();
        //   loopLots(i + 1, newLotCombinations[i + 1].length);
        loopLots(0, newLotCombinations[0].length);
      } else {
        console.log(
        "No possible combination for max sum of differences:",
        MAX_SUM_OF_DIFFERENCES
        );
      }
    }
  } else {
        loopLots(0, newLotCombinations[0].length);
  }
};

const getSumOfDifferences = () => {
  let sumOfDifferences = 0;

  newLotCombinations.forEach((lots, i) => {
    const lotSum = lots.reduce((sum, lot) => {
      sum += lot;
      return sum;
    }, 0);
    const difference = lotSum - oldLots[i];

    if (difference > 0) {
      sumOfDifferences += difference;
    }
  });

  return sumOfDifferences;
};

loopLots();
```

The logic of using `newLotCombinations[i].length < 2` is incorrect, because it keeps pushing in the same alternating numbers. If I memoize the paths to check whether I should go further, how can I know when I am walking backward or forward if simply saving the paths that I have walked through?

I am thinking I also should not save a subset path. I should save a path that reaches the end (i.e. 6), because a subset of path contains unknown paths ahead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: What I have so far is too long for a comment. Let me edit the post and include that.